# Zero and Megaman Zero? What is the difference?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-3

I am so confused, in Zero's ending on Marvel vs Capcom 3, Silver Surfer takes Zero to the wrong world. Zero says that he is NOT Megaman Zero. What is the difference I thought there was only one Zero.

Comment: What exactly is "the wrong world" in this scenario? Which world did he take him to?

Comment: he took him to "Neo-Arcadia", which I thought was the right place, (and it is) but Zero says that it wasn't his world cause he was not "Megaman Zero".

Comment: @JustinCoolestnerdRobinson, he says "yes.. this is indeed Neo Arc.. wait.. something is wrong". Though the discussion that follows, I interpret that it is the right world, in the wrong dimension. Like SS had taken him to an alternate reality of his true world.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one Zero. The Zero featured in the Megaman X and Megaman Zero series are the same, although Zero is 100 years older in the Megaman Zero series.  The Marvel Vs Capcom 3 cut scenes are non-canon, and play no role in the storylines of the respective franchises.

The [Mega Man wiki](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Zero) contains the full history of the character if you are interested.

Comment: So what he is saying is that he is not Megaman Zero BUT Zero meant only for the purposeses MvC3?

Comment: @JustinCoolestnerdRobinson it doesn't mean anything, it's just a joke. The Marvel vs Capcom 3 cut scenes are only intended for entertainment purposes. They are in no way canon.

Comment: Oh ok gotcha ... I thought they at least tried to make them make sense in the universe I guess the Zero one is just a bad joke. would have been cool if they made it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that megaman zero is Zero`s soul in his new body from the zero series. Zero, x, and the sage reploids are all called megamen.

Answer (score 0):

Zero and Megaman Zero are not the same, that was what Capcom was trying to clear up. Think about it, why would Capcom even say that at all. Because they knew people would ask what happened to Megaman Zero. People let me tell you this, video games never go from home console to handheld's, the home console is Megaman X's universe and the GBA was Megaman Zero's universe.

Story wise the two run side by side but the outcome was not the same. Yes Megaman x6 x7 x8 was cannon whether you like it or not. And things don't match up from the Zero universe to the X so yes Capcom was right to show this.

Comment: And what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score -1):

From a [Yahoo! Answers post by user, Quinn](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110702192001AAtjoCm):

> Mega Man X is Dr.Light's final and finest creation, the most advanced robot in the world, a robot capable of human emotions and self thought. X was found by the leading autority of robotics of his time Dr.Cain. Copying X's complex curcuitry, Dr.Cain and X created the reploids, replicated androids, and ushered in a new age of advanced robots. X joined the Maverick Hunters, a reploid police force that protects the innocent from rampaging reploids who become irregular, or maverick.
>
> X is blue like his predecessor Mega man and uses an X-buster, an advanced arm cannon with upgradable systems that not only allows weapon copying, but also weapon charging with the right upgrade
>
> Zero is the final creation and greatest masterpiece of Dr.Wily, the rival and enemy of Dr.Light. Zero was created to be the strongest robot in the world, and its greatest destroyer. Zero was created with the Zero Virus, a deadly program that corrupts and changes a robot into a mindless destructive machine.
>
> Zero was discovered by a unit of Maverick Hunters who cornered him in an old laboratory and was considered a deadly maverick that destroyed many reploids and corrupted more with his virus. Eventually, Zero was subdued by the most advanced and strongest Hunter, Sigma, and couldn't recall his past or his destructive behavior. He has since joined the Maverick Hunters and under Sigma's training quickly rose to high rank and leader of his own unit.
>
> Zero is red-orange robot with long flowing blonde hair who specializes in hand to hand combat with a beam sabre, he also possesses his own Z-Buster arm cannon. Rather than given the ability to copy and integrate the weapon of an opponent, he instead has the ability to learn its skill
>
> The Megaman X series is a moderately challenging series geared toward mature players. 
>   Megaman Zero is a game series starring Zero, which is definitely geared toward advanced players. It is set 100 years after the X series.